# How to insert table view cell in table view while scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I'm currently working on a stream of data displayed in a `UITableView` instance. New items are added at the top of the table view.

The problem I'm facing is that a slight interruption of animations and gestures is visible when a new item is added to the table view. The hiccup occurs both when the table view is decelerating after dragging (animation) as well as when the table view is being dragged.

So far, I've tried removing any insertion animations as well as compensating for the insertion by updating the table view's `contentOffset`. Neither of these approaches seem to work.

Comment: does your cell have image? if yes where are you converting the image url/data to image

Comment: @CharanGiri The table view cell does contain an image view, but the scrolling issue isn't caused by fetching an image or resizing it. The issue is caused by the table view inserting the table view cell at the top of the table view.

Comment: you means if array contains 5 objects then you are displaying like 43210 in this case can you show the cell configure code

Comment: @BartJacobs did you find a solution for this problem? I'm kinda sorta having to solve the same nightmare here....

Comment: @AdrianSalazar It's been a while, but I don't recall having found a solution I was happy with. My suggestion is to update the table view when it isn't scrolling or interacted with by the user.

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with this problem. I was trying to add new rows to a tableView when it reached the last row. You cannot do this whenever you want or you end up with a choppy animation or a sudden stop on the tableView animation.

I figured out that you cannot start a beginAnimations/endAnimations block before the animation (or user drag gesture) ends. To accomplish this, you have to check for two methods:

-**`-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`**: This will tell you when a user stops dragging the tableView, possibly at the end of the tableView. If `willDecelerate` is NO, that is telling you that the user is "holding" its finger on the tableView and has just lifted it. It is a good place to add your rows. You can download the Twitter App to have a look at an example of this. Try to hold your finger at the last row. The App will not update the tweets until you lift it.

**`-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`** This will tell you the user has touched the table view and is finishing it deceleration, possibly at the end of the table view. It is a good place to update your tableView too.

Have a look at this code example:

```
-(void)shouldUpdateOnScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView{
    // Check if we are at the end of the tableView
    CGFloat currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

    // Change 10.0 to adjust the distance from bottom you want to check for
    if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 10.0) {
        // Do not throw an update if we are just updating
        if (!_loading &&  !_allDownloaded) {
            _loading = YES;
            // dispatch_async just to not break the current animation
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self obtainNextPostsFromBegining:NO];
            });

        }
    }
}


-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    NSLog(@"%@ %@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),decelerate?@"YES":@"NO");
    if (!decelerate) {
        // the user has just lifted it's finger. Check if we have to update
        [self shouldUpdateOnScrollView:scrollView];
    }

}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    // the tableView has just stopped. Check if we have to update
    [self shouldUpdateOnScrollView:scrollView];
}
```

Comment: That's the solution I ended up using (see my response to Adrian Salazar's comment), but I'm afraid it isn't an answer to the initial problem. I'm actually doubting if it's possible to insert cells into a table view while it scrolling.

Comment: No, you cannot interrupt an animation while other is animating... :(

Comment: you can with this :
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate date]];
but, u need to use it carefully and remember :
1.call this only when the data to insert is completed and ready
2.consider that other task that waited to execute in main thread can be called

Comment: @user1105951 But, will this insert the cells *while* scrolling? Could you provide a sample?

Comment: yes. this will insert the cells while scrolling.

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
       if(self.feedEdgeConnection.fbRequestNextFeeds) //fbRequestNextFeeds is facebook object
        {
             [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate date]];
        }
    }
}

Comment: you give the main thread "air" WHILE you requesting from facebook the next results.
this way, when results arrived, the main thread can execute the insertion.

i always looking for better way cause giving this "air" to main thread can also execute other tasks. hope this helps. let me know.

Comment: @user1105951 but this is not exactly what we where talking about. You request nextFeeds while giving main thread "air" as you said. We can do that in background with operations or grand central dispatch, but do you **INSERT new cells** while the tableView is scrolling?

Comment: @Pablo Romeu
yes.yes.yes :)
the "air" is giving WHILE requesting UNTIL results coming and INSERTED.
then the "air" is stopped when the request object is nil.
feel free to update.

Comment: @PabloRomeu
a better way I found is using setDelegateQueue (NSUrlConnection)
this will return the results on background thread WHILE scrolling
and calling to disatch_async(main) will update UI , WHILE scrolling.

so, find out if your web service object support delegateQueue.

Comment: @user1105951I tried to do something like that using a dispatch_async, and if you insert rows while the tableView is scrolling, there's a weird behavior: It suddenly goes to the first cell or jumps to the last, etc. no matter if you insert the cells AFTER the one you are currently on. If I try to insert cells while scrolling it does not scroll smoothly. You have to wait until it stops scrolling.... :(